# Converting Hall-effect sensor data to encoder data

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, three-phase, hall-effect

I want to design a sensored BLDC motor controller, but I have a question.

How can I convert sensor data from Hall effect to encoder data?

Can I convert Hall effects to encoder data correctly when I read from the interrupt pins of a microcontroller?

Comment: You can use a Hall effect sensor and a couple of little magnets: https://i.imgur.com/k6kl7X2.png

Comment: You’d want to avoid using the interrupt pins and use a microcontroller that has hardware support for an encoder. What sort of encoder data do you want?

Comment: Sometimes MCU may not capture some hall datas and actually i don't know what is the ic used at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Normally Hall effect sensors are arranged in a way they give information about rotor position, in order to correctly drive the motor coils. For a six-step BLDC you will have 6 different configuration and, for each one, a different configuration of the output bridges.

You can obtain more information simply by measuring the time between each commutation, or counting the number of commutations in a fixed period. Measuring time between Hall changes is good for slow speed - counting commutations in a fixed period of time is good for higher speeds.

"Encoder data", as you call it, can be different things, for example it can be A and B signals of a quadrature encoder, or a PWM signal or something else. And those "encoder data" are normally decoded to obtain speed and position. But you don't need "encoder data" if you have Hall sensors, unless you want to generate those "encoder data" to be output to some other device. Reading correctly (interrupt) the Hall sensors will give you speed and position (in number of commutations), but it is true that an encoder, normally, has much more resolution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , can you advise any ic to read high resolution hall effect sensors data ?

Comment: @omerkarslioglu: I don't know what you mean with "high resolution ... sensors". I think they do not exist. There are simple hall effect sensors, and "high resolution (probably optical) encoders". They are different, and you don't use an IC to cope with them.